# This code is saying Invalid Syntax, and pointing out at my "guessNum" variable. What is wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

```
from random import randint

myNumber = randint(1000,9999)
guessNum = 0
correctNumbers = 0
Input = False
Userguess = 0

print ("Welcome to Guess The Number")
print ("try to guess my number between 1000 and 9999")

while Input == False:
    Userguess = int(raw_input("Guess a number betweeb 1000 and 9999: ")
    guessNum += 1
    if Userguess == myNumber:
        print("Well Done, you guessed the number in" + str(NumberGuesses) + "guesses")
        Input = True
```

The program is a guess the number game where the user has to guess a randomly generated number between `1000` and `9999`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing bracket at line no 13.

```
Userguess = int(raw_input("Guess a number betweeb 1000 and 9999: "))
```

Comment: also at line no 17

Comment: undefined variable : NumberGuesses